# I want to check which variable isset in the array?

Tags: php, isset

```
<?php 
  $tabs = array($auth_name, $pub_name, $lang_name); 
?>
<li class="active">
  <a href="#authors" data-toggle="tab">Authors</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#languages" data-toggle="tab">Languages</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#publishers" data-toggle="tab">Publishers</a>
</li>
```

**How to apply active class on list-item according to isset variable?**

Comment: Can you post how you are generating the list?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="<?php if(isset($tabs)){ echo 'active'; } ?>">
<a href="#authors" data-to....and so on
```

Comment: This is working, but i think its not a proper solution.

print isset($auth_name) ? "<li class='active'><a href='#authors' data-toggle='tab'>Authors</a></li>" : "<li><a href='#authors' data-toggle='tab'>Authors</a></li>";

print isset($lang_name) ? "<li class='active'><a href='#languages' data-toggle='tab'>Languages</a></li>" : "<li><a href='#languages' data-toggle='tab'>Languages</a></li>";

print isset($pub_name) ? "<li class='active'><a href='#publishers' data-toggle='tab'>Publishers</a></li>" : "<li><a href='#publishers' data-toggle='tab'>Publishers</a></li>";